# Extract sentences from texts in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column "text" and in each row of my data frame "text" contains several sentences (maybe only two, maybe 100 or more). Now I would like to analyze the text in every row of my data frame for specific keywords. If a keyword is found in the text of this row I would like to extract the sentences, which contain keywords, to a separate column, f.e.

```
needles = c("first", "hope", "analyze", "happy")

mydata <- data.frame(
  text = c("This is the first sentence. It is the beginning of this project",
           "My second sentence is this. I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence.",
           "And this is the last sentence. Finally my work ends. I am really happy about that.",
           "These sentences do not contain any relevant information. There is no keyword. And it is not relevant."),
  findings = c("This is the first sentence.",
               "I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence.",
               "I am really happy about that.",
               NA)
)
```

So column "text" contains the sentences I want to check for keywords, "findings" is the result I would like to have in the end.

Can anyone help me how to apply the solution for all rows of the data frame?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the tidytext package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can work with list columns by splitting each row in different sentences and look for the needles inside each resulting sentence of each row.

The `reduce` functions are to take levels of depth of the lists.

code:

```r
library(tidyverse)


needles <- c("first", "hope", "analyze", "happy")

mydata <- data.frame(
  text = c(
    "This is the first sentence. It is the beginning of this project",
    "My second sentence is this. I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence.",
    "And this is the last sentence. Finally my work ends. I am really happy about that.",
    "These sentences do not contain any relevant information. There is no keyword. And it is not relevant."
  ),
  findings = c(
    "This is the first sentence.",
    "I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence.",
    "I am really happy about that.",
    NA
  )
)



df <- as_tibble(mydata) %>% 
mutate(mydata, findings = str_split(text, "\\.\\s") %>%
         map(~str_subset(., rebus::or1(needles))) %>% 
         map_if(~length(.) > 1, ~reduce(., ~paste(.x, .y, sep = '. '))),
       findings = map_if(findings, ~length(.) == 0, ~NA) %>% reduce(c))


df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   text                                    findings                              
#>   <chr>                                   <chr>                                 
#> 1 This is the first sentence. It is the … This is the first sentence            
#> 2 My second sentence is this. I hope thi… I hope this project will work fine. T…
#> 3 And this is the last sentence. Finally… I am really happy about that.         
#> 4 These sentences do not contain any rel… <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This uses `grep` and a `strsplit` to get the matches.

```
mydata$findings <- sapply( strsplit( t(mydata), "\\. " ), function(x)
                     x[unlist( lapply( needles, function(y) grep(y, x) ) )] )

                                                                                                     text
1                                         This is the first sentence. It is the beginning of this project
2 My second sentence is this. I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence.
3                      And this is the last sentence. Finally my work ends. I am really happy about that.
4   These sentences do not contain any relevant information. There is no keyword. And it is not relevant.
                                                                     findings
1                                                  This is the first sentence
2 I hope this project will work fine, Then I will analyze the third sentence.
3                                               I am really happy about that.
4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
find_sentence <- function(text, word){
  require(stringr)
  x <- c(str_split(text, "\\..", simplify=TRUE))
  inds <- which(str_detect(x, word))
  if(length(inds) > 0){
    list(x[inds])
  }else{
    list(NA)
  }
  
}

mydata %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(res = find_sentence(text, "the")) %>% 
  unnest(res)

# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   text                                                                                                    findings                     res            
#   <chr>                                                                                                   <chr>                        <chr>          
# 1 This is the first sentence. It is the beginning of this project                                         This is the first sentence.  This is the fi…
# 2 This is the first sentence. It is the beginning of this project                                         This is the first sentence.  It is the begi…
# 3 My second sentence is this. I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence. I hope this project will wo… Then I will an…
# 4 And this is the last sentence. Finally my work ends. I am really happy about that.                      I am really happy about tha… And this is th…
```

This returns a new variable called `res` that has a different row for each occurrence of the keyword in a sentence.  So, if two sentences contained the word (as in the first sentence in `text`), the `text` and `findings` columns will be replicated for each of the relevant sentences in `res`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

With `Base R`,

```
lookup <- strsplit(as.character(mydata[,1]),"\\.")

out <- lapply(lookup,function(x) { 
                logic <- grepl(paste0(needles,collapse="|"),x)
                paste0(x[logic],collapse=".")


            })


data.frame(findings = do.call(rbind,out) )
```

gives,

```
#                                                                     findings
#1                                                  This is the first sentence
#2  I hope this project will work fine. Then I will analyze the third sentence
#3                                                I am really happy about that
#4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!